# Enabling Remote Access in Apache Tomcat

Tags: android, web-services, tomcat7, netbeans-7

I have created web services in NetBeans using Apache Tomcat as server. These web services are to be called from the code in eclipse for android . While implementing this I am getting ConnectTimeoutException and I am not able to connect to server. I want to know how I can configure the Tomcat server to be able to accessible from outside.

Comment: Are you able to access the server from your local machine (e.g. from your web browser)?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access server from my browser @AshuPachauri

Comment: Just to keep the matters less complicated make sure you don't have apache http server running for the time being. Now, whenever you see that server is not accessible from network, it is almost invariably firewall issue. Did you try opening the port for incoming connections using iptables/firewall?

Comment: @AshuPachauri yes it was firewall issue. Thanks.